# themoviedb Search Movie 401 error

Tags: themoviedb-api

I am on themoviedb.org to understand request and response for search movie. I am received api_key. When I try to use their console on the site with api_key and query. I am getting 401 error.

The detailed error message is:
status code 7
status message invalid api key

If I use the same key in my code, I dont receive any error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by Apiary expecting the API key to be sent as a header as opposed to what TMDb expects (which is just a query parameter).

If you add the 'api_key' as a query parameter to your URL instead, it should work.